# Editable dropdown in bootstrap - dropdown goes out of col-x bound

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I m currently trying to create an editable dropdown list for my web site, after some googling it seems the easiest way is to put a textbox on top of the dropdown and pass the text to the textbox when selected, this works for fine but when it applies this principle to twitter-bootstrap, I could not figure out how the align the css part (the dropdown width always go outside the col-boundary), can I ask if anyone could provide me with some lights please?

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">Name</span>
      <select id="cboName" name="cboName" class="form-control editDropDown-select"  onchange="this.nextElementSibling.value=this.value">
            <option value="John">John</option>
            <option value="Peter">Peter</option>
            <option value="Mary">Mary</option>                                         
        </select>
      <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">Other</span>
      <input type="text" id="other" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.editDropDown-select
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;   
    width:100px; 
}
```

**JSFiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/gfruxn7q/

Comment: I have made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/cgburf0m/1/) with your code. Can you tell me what issue are you talking about?

Comment: Thanks, for looking it up. I have updated question (with a fiddle), What I m trying to achieve is that to make sure the dropdown stays in place of the col boundary, with the textbox on top of the dropdown (mincing an vb style combobox)

Comment: You can remove the absolute position of the select and hide the textfield. Is that what you want?

Comment: Not quite, as I need the capability of both selecting items from the dropdown as well as the type in custom text, hiding it would defeat the point having the two controls. Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/nwH8A/ would be ideal (but work with bootstrap)

Comment: [Check this](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/gfruxn7q/3/). I had to give !important for setting the border radius for the select as it's not actually the last element.

Comment: Thanks, this is closest thing I need, however text box still overlap the whole dropdown when I shrink the browser, but this is good enough for me, thanks again for your help. (I would like to mark this as the answer but not sure how it can be done within comments)

Comment: Yeah, you may have to target those classes using media queries as bootstrap changes the width for different devices.